# Div inside others (with margin-top) is pushing parents down

Tags: html, css

When I was working on a little project I ran into a delema I can't for the life of me figure out. Why is it that the div inside **#appHead** is causing **#windowBody** to move down? Any Ideas?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Atlas - Valencia College</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bgGrad"></div>
        <div id="windowTop">
        </div>
        <div id="windowBody">
            <div id="appEnv">
                <div id="appHead">
                    <div style="margin-top:20px;height:20px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="windowFoot">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

> body{
>         background:url("lol.png");
>         margin:0;
>       }
>       #appEnv{
>         width:100%;
>         height:100%;
>         top:0;
>         bottom:0;
>         left:0;
>         right:0;
>         outline:dotted 1px blue; 
>       }
>       #appHead{
>         height:100px;
>       }
>       #windowBody{
>         position:absolute;
>         top:0;
>         width:100%;
>         bottom:0;
>       }

Even when I removed all of the absolute positioning, it was still the case, however I may have done it wrong.

Comment: It's called collapsing margins, there are a few ways around it: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

Comment: James, you should have made it an answer, that's what I'm looking for and would have made it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I played with this a bit and here's what I've found:

First, #windowBody is not being moved down. If you slap a border on it you'll see that it doesn't move regardless of other changes. It's actually #appHead that moves.

In your code, you have no content in the appHead div, but have instead thrown another div into it that includes a margin-top. Because there's no content in #appHead it basically gets merged into it's child div and gains it's margin-top attribute, moving it down by 20px (you can change the 20px to another number to see the change). Adding even a single word to #appHead (but not inside it's child div) will totally solve the problem.

You can play around with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/tsuujin/QcpgC/

Comment: It also works if you put a transparent border on appHead, even though it seems like an ugly solution. But thanks very much for this! Was scratching my head when I encountered this!

Answer (score 2):

A slightly safer way is also to add

```
#appHead:after {
 content:"";
 display:block;
 clear:both;
 font-size:0;
 line-height:0;
}
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: This is a good alternative to the solution I provided. It _may_ cause some issues with background formatting, but you may not need that anyways.

Comment: you may also get issues with some older browsers with :after, try it and test on your target devices

Answer (score 0):

Use `border` in place of `outline` on your #appEnv element.

```
{
 border: dotted 1px blue;
}
```

Comment: True enough. Not sure why there was an outline instead of a border.. but it doesn't fix the problem with you make this change.

Comment: @Nathan Cox, That is true, I apparently misunderstood the question originally asked :)

Comment: outline was there for debug, border alters element dimentions

Answer (score 0):

The margin will stop pushing everything up when you apply

```
   float: left;
```

(or right) to the div inside #appHead.

Comment: This also will work, but you need to be careful to only float items you actually want floated. Trust me when I say that using floats can create a totally different set of frustrations.

Comment: Well using float will interrupt the documentflow which will let following elements sneak behind the floated element. But once you know that you can just continue the documentflow with clear at any point. Confusing concept at first, but definitely worth it.

Answer (score 0):

When not using a reset stylesheet I've always found that top margin screw up the page flow when close to the top of the dom. Along with the other answers you can also add `overflow:hidden` to the `#appHead` styles

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your end goal, you could consider in your CSS try adding to `#appEnv`

`position:absolute;`

Comment: This does work, but only if you didn't want #appEnv to be positioned inside of it's parent div properly (absolute positioning is... absolute).